# Fastlane CI Getting Stuck when Using XCode 13 on [CP] Embed Pod Frameworks Step

Tags: xcode, github-actions, fastlane, xcode13, fastlane-match

After moving my CI (Github Actions) to use XCode 13 this week, Fastlane builds are getting stuck at the [CP] Embed Pod Frameworks step.

I've read that this can be due to keychain issues and tried a number of approaches including deleting the keychain and creating a new one before calling match. It hasn't worked.

Would appreciate some advice here.

Comment: What is the exact issue/error here?

Comment: It gets frozen at the [CP] Embed Pod Frameworks step and doesn't move forward. Most likely it's asking for keychain to use with Match. Works when I change CI XCode version to 12.4